# How to for loop with iterators if vector type is parent of two child types filling vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iterator, sfml, stdvector

I have this problem:

this is my loop for previously used child type

```
std::vector<Coin>::iterator coin;

for (coin = coinVec.begin(); coin != coinVec.end(); ++coin)
{

    sf::FloatRect coinBounds = coin->getGlobalBounds();

    if (viewBox.intersects(coinBounds))
    {

        if (playerBounds.intersects(coinBounds))
        {
            coin = coinVec.erase(coin);
            break;
        }
        else coin->setTextureRect(currentFrame);

    }
}
```

And the similar one for `std::vector<Heal>`.

I rebuild my code structure to: Coin is now child of Collectables.

There is now only one vector: `std::vector<Collectables>` which contains all collactable child  classes objects like Coin, Heal etc.. Is there a way to make the code work with only one loop and iterators? If yes, how would you do that?

Thanks

Comment: Well, we can't see the relevant code, but you can't store polymorphic types in a vector like that.  You will experience [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: I think that wouldnt be a problem, My ,for example, Health class doesnt contains object of type Collectables, it only inherits from it 90% of content shared with another child classes.. And primary usage of Collectables is to simplify my code. I can use like, std::Vector<Collectables>... .push_back(healthObject); and that makes a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that my code is so universal, that I dont need to separate vector elements at all.

My solution here:

```
std::vector<Collectables>::iterator collect;

for (collect = collectVec.begin(); collect != collectVec.end(); ++collect)
{

    sf::FloatRect collectBounds = collect->getGlobalBounds();

    if (viewBox.intersects(collectBounds))
    {

        if (playerBounds.intersects(collectBounds))
        {
            collect = collectVec.erase(collect);
            break;
        }
        else collect->setTextureRect(currentFrame);

    }
}
```

And if you really need to separate elements, try this:

```
if (collect->getType() == ResourceManager::enums::textures::coin)
{

} else
    if (collect->getType() == ResourceManager::enums::textures::health)
    {

    }
```

Where getType stores simply int id matching enum value.

Answer (score 0):

Although seems that you have solved the problem, it is probably worth to tell how would you solve the initial problem.
As mentioned in the comments storing elements in the vector would result in object slicing, e.g.

```
std::vector<BaseClass> vect;
```

The elements of the vector would be able to store information about objects, which is common for classes, aka defined in `BaseClass`. If you want to be able to perform [polymorphism](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)(which you are trying to achieve in the example), you should store vector of pointers like this.

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> vect;
```

Each pointer would point to the address of the element, and thus object slicing won't happen.

Comment: I tryed your way, but I have problem using iterator in my for loop with that double pointer vector. How would you do that?

Comment: At first you had iterator `coin`, which you used like `coin->some_member`. Now, when you have an iterator of vector of pointers, you could have done `*(coin)->some_member`